# Can I somehow force Einstein to build it's recommendation lists for all product brands that I have in my product catalog?

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, einstein-recommendations

I have a custom field named Brand inside my product catalog. Is there a way to have Einstein build it's recommendation lists based on this field, so that every brand would always have recommendations? I have already marked this field as "Tag Field" inside product catalog but when I check under `Email Recommendations->Reporting->Admin Tools->Lists`, most of the brands have no lists.

Comment: Do you have three products master products (UUID~1) that have OA = Y with those tags?

Comment: @EazyE can you explain a bit more about what you mean? What is OA = Y?

Comment: Availability = Y

Comment: @EazyE Yes, all the products within the catalog have Online Availability = Y.